# Change javascript regex divider character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple JS question.

I have this code, and what I need is cut the textbox value every two characters (this works fine), but I want to change the comma with the column.

My actual result is:
stringtest - st,ri,ng,te,st

and I want this:

stringtest - st:ri:ng:te:st

my code is:

```
function test() {
    var textboxtext= $("#textbox").val();
    var splitted = textboxtext.match(/.{2}|.{1,2}/g);
    alert("B8:27:EB:" + splitted)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the regex, but with how you're converting the result array to a string. When the JavaScript engine needs to convert an array to a string (which is done implicitly when you use the binary `+` operator with an string on either side), it calls the [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) method, which basically just calls the [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method, which returns a string with each element of the array converted to a string, and separated by commas.

But you can call the `join` method yourself and specify what character you'd like it to use as a separator, like this:

```
alert("B8:27:EB:" + splitted.join(':'));
```

On a side note, you can simplify your regex to `.{1,2}`, which is exactly the same as what you had previously:

```
var splitted = textboxtext.match(/.{1,2}/g);
```